# How do I create an alert dialog asking users to subscribe to my site using js?

Tags: javascript, cookies

When someone is on my site I want my site to show an alert or confirm prompt asking the user to subscribe to my mailing list. I want the message to show up shortly but not immediately, Have the ok option direct the users to the subscribe page, 2 other options (I already subscribed, dismiss)

When they dismiss the option I want my site to leave a cookie on their computer for 7 days. When the cookie is active the prompt doesn't show. If the user clicks (I already subscribed) I want the cookie to last forever.

Is it possible for the subscribe page to leave a non expiring cookie to disable the subscribe prompt? If cookies only work with the url they were sent from I do have the option "I already subscribed"

Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1h7X.png) of a flowchart of the problem I want to solve

Comment: Yes, you can set a cookie to last "forever", but you cannot have 3 options, only 2 for `confirm`. You can use a `prompt` and instruct the user to type in the option they want. Or, you can use custom dialog using HTML + CSS + JS, creating it on your own or using a library like [bootboxjs](http://bootboxjs.com/) or similar.

Comment: please provide code with some logic.

Comment: Your question is too broad, SO is for questions about a specific programming problems. What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#subscribeModal').modal('show');
            }, 5000);

            $("#btnRegister").click(function () {
                var email = $("#txtEmailAddress").val();
                alert("Handle the subscription logic for - " + email);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="subscribeModal" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Subscribe To My Site</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Your email address
                        <input type="email" id="txtEmailAddress">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnRegister">Subscribe</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```